# Nodejs can't get post request body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I  created nodejs api and react app and I dockerized them.

When I try to send a post request through api, the request body getting empty.

I created api docker container like this:

```
FROM node:lts
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# Copy app source code
COPY . .

#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I also created react app container like this:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I double checked to express json  middleware in nodejs:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
```

I am sending post request like this in react app:

```
fetch(`${serviceUrl}/metrics`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(getPerfanalytics().values),
})
```

I can see that request is working good but  the  request body is  empty always.

Here is how can I get post request:

```
    export const saveMetric = (req, res) => {
        let params = req.body;
        console.log(params);
        if (typeof params === 'string') {
            params = JSON.parse(params)
        }
        new Metric(params).save().then(metric => {
            res.json({
                message: 'Metric saved',
                data: metric
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(500);
            res.json({
                message: 'Metric saving error',
                error: err
            });
        }

);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What’s the serviceUrl that you’re using?

Comment: Can you also post the nodejs handler for the `/metrics` route? In addition, you might need to specify the `Content-Type` header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data

Comment: @Joe http://localhost:4000. it is api endpoint. It works perfectly. There is no problem with the endpoint.

Comment: Does your express json middleware on top of express router middleware?

Comment: Did you make sure to add the `json()` middleware *before*  you added the specific route handler? And can you try adding the `express.json()` middleware on the respective route only instead of on the whole router `app.post("/metrics", express.json(), saveMetric)`.

Comment: @segFault After setting `Content-Type`  I restarted docker containers. Yes it solved by doing this. Actually I tried before it hadnt been resolved. Maybe it was about container building problem.

Comment: did u add body parser middleware